# Proper way to call MediaPlayer.isPlaying() without ANR?

Tags: java, android

In my app I have a service that plays audio, that service just has a single static `MediaPlayer` object. In `onStart()` from my main activity where I call `MediaPlayer.isPlaying();` to determine which UI elements to show, I get an ANR message and a `NullPointerException` at the line where I call `MediaPlayer.isPlaying();`

I also call `MediaPLayer.isPlaying();` when certain buttons are pressed, and that causes ANR as well, I discovered that after i took away the `MediaPlayer.isPlaying();` call in `onStart();`, since I couldn't get past that without an ANR...

I found this similar question: [MediaPlayer isPlaying() always returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306915/mediaplayer-isplaying-always-returning-false)

Where someone says: "Also, while we're on the general MediaPlayer subject, note that isPlaying() can cause an ANR when called on the UI thread. In fact, Google recommends executing all MediaPlayer calls from a background handler thread. Which will also serialize execution of MediaPlayer calls."

I couldn't find anything in documentation about this. So how do I or what is the best way to create a short lived thread in these scenarios so I am able to check the status of my `MediaPlayer`? Or is there another way?

Comment: post some relevant code and logcat error will help

Comment: It has a few bugs as suggested by answers on the other post. As per his suggestion, you can use your own isPlaying flag.

Comment: I see, you mean something like when my music is actually playing i manually set a boolean to true and false when it stops etc? Because ive tried having a flag based off MediaPlayer.isPlaying() and that crashes too...