# MediaPlayer isPlaying() method returns false while playing

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

For some unknown reason the `MediaPlayer` `isPlaying()` method is returning false while video is playing.

Is there a structure or a required way to call the `MediaPlayer` methods in chronological order so that false isn't returned while the MediaPlayer is playing ?

heres how Im calling the `methodmediaPlayer.isPlaying();` really simple and straight forward its just that its not returning the true when it should.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MediaPlayer isPlaying() always returning false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306915/mediaplayer-isplaying-always-returning-false)

Comment: @HongDuan I saw that answer its just not really an answer just suggestions :(